# How to write unit test case for Angular 2 Reactive forms by using Karma/Jasmine?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I have develop a simple reactive form in Angular 2, Which includes `username`, `password` and `login` buttons. Here button default disable up to getting email and password values. Here i am trying to write a test case for button enable by using `karma/Jasmine`, But i am new to this testing framework, I have written normal valid and invalid things,but not getting clarity to write this particular thing. If any one aware of this, could you please help me to quick start.

This is my reactive form:

```html
<nb-card *ngIf="!loading" >
    <nb-card-header>
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>Sign In Form </nb-card-header>
    <nb-card-body>
        <form [formGroup]="authForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" >
            <input id="userid" type="text" class="bx--text-input" placeholder="EOSE Userid" 
            formControlName="userid" [attr.data-invalid]="useridMessage ? '' : null"/> 
            
            <div class="bx--form-requirement" *ngIf="useridMessage">{{ useridMessage }} </div> 
              <br>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="bx--text-input" placeholder="EOSE Password" 
            formControlName="password" [attr.data-invalid]="passwordMessage ? '' : null"/> 
            <div class="bx--form-requirement" *ngIf="passwordMessage" >{{ passwordMessage }} </div>
            
           <br>
            <carbon-button type="primary" [disabled]="!authForm.valid">Sign In</carbon-button>  
        </form> 
    </nb-card-body>  
</nb-card>
```

This is my `.spec` file.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginFormComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
  it('form should be invalid', async(() => {
    component.authForm.controls['userid'].setValue('');
    component.authForm.controls['password'].setValue('');
    expect(component.authForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
  }));
```

Comment: Do you want to write a test case to check if button is disabled or not?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yes, exactltly. If we give input data to the both fields button should enable otherwise button will disable.

Answer (score 4):

Test case to check if button is disabled or not

```
it('form should be invalid', async(() => {
    component.authForm.controls['userid'].setValue('');
    component.authForm.controls['password'].setValue('');
    expect(component.authForm.valid).toBeFalsy();

    // update view, once the values are entered
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('carbon-button'));  // fetch button element
    expect(btn.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();  // check if it is disabled
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Which you have written this test case should be pass right because button will be disable state. But this is failing with the error is"Expected undefined to be truthy."

Answer (score 2):

Test case for form validation.

component:

```
public buildFrom() {
   this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      'email': [undefined, Validators.required],
      'password': [undefined, Validators.required]
   });
}
```

Test Case:

```
function setFormValues(fromData) {
 component.loginFrom.control['email].setValue(fromData.email);
 component.loginFrom.control['password].setValue(fromData.password);
}

it('should have form valid", () => {
 component.buildFrom();
 const data = {
   email: 'xyz@abc.com',
   password: 'xyz'
 };
 setFormValues(data);
 expect(component.loginFrom.valid).toBeTruthy();
})


it('should have password', ()=> {
 component.buildFrom();
 const data = {
   email: 'abc@abc.com',
   password: 'abc'
 };
 setFormValues(data);
 expect(component.loginFrom.get('password').value.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
})
```